# How can I stack divs on float?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Site: http://bit.ly/13nL8jV 
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bBckp/

Brief: I am trying to get the CURRENT PROGRAMS to float under the SIGNATURE PROGRAMS with no luck. All of the columns in the footer have the CSS:

```
float: left;
width: 29%;
```

The columns are dynamic so I can't just wrap SIGNATURE and CURRENT in it's own div (I can probably hack it with JS)...CLARRIFICATION - I'm referring to the menus in the FOOTER.

Any thoughts how I can do this with just CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can tweak the element like so. This does leave a hole where it used to be, but that's what relative positioning does.

```
.item-130 {
   position:relative;
   left:-180px;
   top:25px
}
```

Alternately you can set the parent UL to `position:relative`, and use absolute positioning:

```
.nav-pills {
    position:relative;
}

.item-130 {
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:25px
}
```

Comment: sorry. CLARRIFICATION - I'm referring to the menus in the FOOTER

Answer (score 0):

it may help you

html like this way;

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="SIGNATURE PROGRAMS">
        ..........
    </div>
    <div class="CURRENT PROGRAMS">
        ..........
    </div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.SIGNATURE PROGRAMS{
  float:left;
}
.CURRENT PROGRAMS{
 clear:both;
}
```

**EDIT::** if you cant change your html..then you may try this

```
.moduletable.current-prog {
  position: relative;
  left: -29%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  }
```

Comment: I don't believe the OP can change the HTML because it is generated by the app.

Comment: sorry, CLARRIFICATION - I'm referring to the menus in the FOOTER

Comment: i have also reffered it

Comment: your `.moduletable  .current-prog` are two classes of your footer

Comment: `.footer->.container->.moduletable .current-prog`

Comment: sorry I don't understand your thought @ritabrata gautam

Comment: if you can edit the html..then follow the part which is wriiten upto edit....put both signature programs div and current program divs in a wrapper and then follow my code

Comment: if you cant change the html mark up...then add a css which is written after edit and your current programs will go under the signature programs...if you are applying it then report me..then we will bring some more changes to make it more beautiful

Comment: I can't change the HTML and your CSS works but I already tried that...but the columns to the right of it do now flow in to fill it's space.